# My php page will display my html header include in the dreamweaver preview but not in a browser

Tags: php, html, include, preview

The snippet of include code in my php file looks like this.

```
<div id="header">
  <!--#include virtual="includes/frontpage_header.html" -->
</div>
```

And my frontpage_header.html code looks like this.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30%;"><a href="../index_new.php"><img id="headerlogo" src="../images/DynamicHomes45th.png" alt="Dynamic Homes Logo"/></a>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
<h1>QUALITY CUSTOM BUILT HOMES</h1>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 33%;">
<div id="headernav">
  <div id="whybuild">
    <h2>WHY BUILD DYNAMIC</h2>
    <img src="../images/whybuildicon.png" alt=""/> </div>
  <div id="gallery">
    <h2>GALLERY</h2>
    <img src="../images/galleryicon.png" width="43" height="43" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Like I said in the title, it will display in my dreamweaver's design view, but not in a browser. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Because it is commented out.

Comment: Serverside Includes only work if they're put through something that supports them. Simply opening the file in a browser will not work.

Comment: @OllyTenerife thats how SSI tags look.

Comment: You can't include one HTML inside another, using pure HTML syntax. Dreamweaver processes it, but web server doesn't.

Comment: @user4035: yes, you can, if the server has SSI (server-side-includes) enabled.

Comment: @MarcB Is HTML with SSI pure HTML?

Comment: yes, because ssi are just html comments for anything that doesn't understand them.

Answer (score 0):

Try including it like this using Php:

```
<div id="header">
    <?php include("includes/frontpage_header.html"); ?>
</div>
```

Also it's worth making this frontpage_header file a .php rather than .html considering you are using Php elsewhere in your project.

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Are the paths correct for the file you are including? Also try changing the frontpage_header to a .php file

Comment: Yea the path should be correct, and I did change it to a php file but still the same result.

Comment: <?php include("/includes/frontpage_header.html"); ?> Try this, with the backslash before the path to point at the root.

Comment: or try simply <?php include '/includes/frontpage_header.php'; ?> without the parentheses.

Comment: Hmm, tried it but now it seems to disappear from my dreamweaver preview as well.

Comment: Tried it without parentheses too and it didn't change anything.

Comment: All file names correct? And the directory structure?

Comment: Try using absolute path: <?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/frontpage_header.php"); ?>

Comment: Everything is named correctly, and the absolute path didn't work either.